# HP 6910p battery charging very slowly

Tags: windows-7, laptop, power-supply, battery, network-adapter

My laptop battery charge rate is very slow. It charges between 50% - 100% in almost 4, 5 hours. 
It's running normal on AC adapter without any problem but running very slow on battery mode. So can one suggest me what is an actual issue with the laptop. I replaced the charger and battery both new and original.Still i am facing the same problem.

Model: HP 6910p
core 2 duo (T7300) 2GHZ
120 GB HDD
2 GB RAM
DVD ROM.

Comment: Has the charging of the battery been ever faster? Did you try an bios update?

Comment: My Acer laptop always charges that slow, are you sure this isn't normal?

Answer (score 0):

Check the voltage and amps on the bottom of the laptop, then check that the power supply is correct. If they are then it is most likely a faulty power supply. Try to get an original UP power supply and not one of the multiple power supplies.